# Last line being printed twice (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a text file called scores.txt with the following data:

```
John T Smith 90
Eric K Jones 103
Ram S Krishnan 25
Marie A Bell 50
```

I am trying to read the data from this file and print it using the following C++ code:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("scores.txt");
string firstName;
char mi;
string lastName;
int score;

while (input) {
    input>>firstName>>mi>>lastName>>score;
    cout<<firstName<<" "<<mi<<" "<<lastName<<" "<<score<<endl;
}

input.close();
cout<<"Done"<<endl;
```

The output is:

```
John T Smith 90
Eric K Jones 103
Ram S Krishnan 25
Marie A Bell 50
Marie A Bell 50
```

Why is the last line (Marie A Bell 50) being printed twice? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You failed to check for the return value of your input operation.

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you mean by that? Sorry, I'm new to C++.

Comment: You're saying "Let `firstName` have the value that's next on the input", but you never admit the possibility in your thinking that there may not be a next value. This is a conceptual failure logic.

Answer (score 6):

It's because just after you read the file's last line, `input` is not yet at *end of file*. Your program enters the `while` loop a fifth time, reads `input` (which set it to its *end of file* state), does not alter your variables and prints them.

A way (amongst many) to avoid this is to write something like

```
while (input >> var1 >> var2)
{
    std::cout << var1 << "," << var2 << std::endl;
}
```