# c - Last call to function is being printed again

Tags: c, loops, printing, while-loop

This is the loop in my a4.c main method that calls the patternsearch function:

```
while(!feof(stdin)) {
scanf("%s", &word); 
patternSearch(grid, word); 
}
```

For some reason that I can't figure out, this prints the last call to patternsearch twice:

For example, look at my output for test3:

```
Found "tip" at 0 2, L
Found "pop" at 0 0, D
Found "pop" at 2 0, U
Found "key" at 0 3, D
Found "key" at 2 1, R
"nope" - Not Found
"nope" - Not Found
```

As you can see, the test result for 'nope' was printed twice. :(

I think my problem is similar to the one stated here:
[Last line being printed twice (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166697/last-line-being-printed-twice-c)
but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that feof() only returned true when I actually hit the EOF character.
That means that I was calling scanf(), and hitting the EOF; 
that means the loop won't iterate again, but I was already in the middle of it.
But scanf() only actually changes the argument I hand it if it successfully reads what I asked; 
since it failed (by hitting EOF), 
it won't change the character array, which will still contain whatever it did before (i.e. the previous word).

I checked the return value of scanf(); the number it returns, which is the number of arguments it put a new value into; 
if that's less than 1, then I didn't actually get a new string  (I think it also explicitly returns EOF if it hits the end-of-file; EOF is a #defined constant that's equal to -1 on most platforms, so the <1 check will work anyway).

This is the code that finally worked:

```
while(!feof(stdin)) {
    if (scanf("%s", &word) < 1)
      break;
    patternSearch(grid, word);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 with any problem involving input: **test the return value from the input function**.

1. `feof()` checks if a *prior* read resulted in an end-of-file.  It does not report about future reads.
2. Code is having trouble with unexpected results of `scanf("%s", &word);`, yet code did not check the return value from `scanf()`.  Weak code does not check the return value.  Robust code does.  Research the proper use of `scanf()` and its return values.
3. Do not use `"%s"` without a width limit.
4. The `&` in `scanf("%s", &word);` is likely not needed.  Would need to see `word` declaration to be sure.

   ```
   char word[100];
   while (scanf("%99s", word) == 1) {
     patternSearch(grid, word); 
   }
   ```